# Разобраться в показаниях lm-sensors

Tags: linux, процессор

Всем привет. Недавно перешел на Linux. Пока все более-менее понятно. А вот с lm-sensors никак подружится не могу.
Если кто в курсе. Объясните что за показания temp1, temp2 и temp3? Где тут температура процессора, сокета?
Материнская плата Asus M2A97 R2.0, процессор AMD FX 6300.
[image: lm-sensors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На просторах Интеренет нарыл следующую информацию https://www.spinics.net/lists/lm-sensors/msg43352.html

для **it8721-isa-0290**

> temp1 - Температура проца
>
> temp2 - Температура сокета

Можно подложить конфигурационный файл в папку /etc/sensors.d/ , тогда вывод будет более "приятный". Содержимое для конфиг файла можно взять из ссылки выше

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь все понятно. Только не разобрался. Как применить этот конфиг. Закинул в папку. А дальше нужно его указать? Кстати. Имя конфига должно быть определенное или произвольное?

Comment: Имя конфига произвольное с расширением .conf Более ничего делать не нужно, его автоматически должно подтягивать при выполнении команды sensors